# How to get VirtualHost Name in my cgi scripts?

Tags: apache, nginx, cgi

I use Nginx as reverse proxy server, and forward request to backend upstreams. 
All backend upstreams are actually NameVirtualHost of Apache2, and they are in the same host.
There is a simple cgi program, written in Bash, gonna to be run by the VirtualHosts described above. My question is, Is there anyway for this cgi script to get the VirtualHost name from which it is running now. Thank you!

Comment: nginx adds optionally `Host` parameter while connecting the backend... if you set it, you can read it in CGI in the same way as you read all other SERVER variables. If in BASH you can try to debug it by putting set > /tmp/.log into your CGI and examining the `/tmp/.log`